# Chart.js only shows old values from an old array

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, chart.js

I have a chart.js graph which receives the values from a .txt file which has them a string (with `fetch()`).
The string gets split and converted into an array with numbers, which will be shown on the chart.js graph.
It's preset 24 x-Values and the y-values which will be sent through the .txt file are calculated before, depending on the input the client gave earlier.

I have 2 problems with my code:

1. the array doesn't seem to update when the client enters new values in the input and the new calculated values will not be shown in the chart.js graph. The text file shows the right values but it's only not correctly updated in the Array and chart.js graph.
2. the first and last value are empty in the chart.js graph (array shows "NaN" for them).

HTML-part where values from .txt file get split and transfered into the array:

```
<button id="submit1" type="button">Graph aktualisieren</button>

<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" class="Simulation">
    <br><br><br>
    <canvas id="graph" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>


    <script>


        //Function starts with "Update graph" button
        submit1.onclick = function () {
            //fetch opens Swerte.txt
            fetch("Swerte.txt")
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.text();
                })
                // writing text in id
                .then(function (txt) {

                    var id = txt;
                    // converting String in int Array
                    let zahlen = id.split(",");
                    var yValues = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++) {
                        let z = Number(zahlen[i]);
                        yValues.push(z);

                    }


                    var xValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];
                    console.log(xValues);
                    console.log(yValues);


                    //Erstellung eines neuen Graphen
                    new Chart("graph", {
                        type: "line",
                        data: {
                            labels: xValues,
                            datasets: [{
                                fill: false,
                                lineTension: 0,
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
                                borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
                                data: yValues
                            }]
                        },
                        //Einstellungen für den Graphen für Titel, Achsen-Titel, Tickrate und Farben
                        options: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Ergebniss Epidemie-Simulation:'
                            },
                            legend: {display: false,},
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {min: 1},
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: 'Infizierte'
                                    }
                                }],
                                xAxes: [{
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: 'Tage'
                                    }
                                }]
                            }

                        }
                    });
                })
        };

    </script>
```

.txt file content (example):

```
[53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30]
```

Normally it should show the new results from the .txt file that got calculated for the first problem and it should also show the first and last value of the chart.js graph.

Can someone help me?

Comment: By input you mean the text file? The user will write in the text file, and you're expecting that it gets directly updated in the chart, that's it?

Comment: There are 2 HTML inputs before which sends the input-values to a cotroller that calculates them and saves the results in a text file which will get fetched in the script. The numbers from the text file should be put in an array and then into the chart and be updated there everytime there are new results and values. For now its only updating when I restart and not when I reload or click the submit button again.

Comment: The not updating part might be due to caching in the browser. Try `fetch("Swerte.txt", { cache: "no-store" })`; see [Request.cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) for reference.

Comment: The missing initial and final values might be due to the fact that you don't eliminate the square brackets from the input. Try `var id = txt.replace(/[[\]]/g, '');` Alternatively, I think replacing all your custom parsing with `var yValues = JSON.parse(txt);` might work for that type of text input.